# Erro ao dar bin/magento indexer:reindex

Tags: magento, cron, permissões, job

O meu painel de controle do Magento fica aparecendo essa mensagem

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
>   running.

Eu vi que teria que dar um `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`mas sempre que eu tento dar isso aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php71/session/sess_8d4b0824fe8a35e6091a8fbec6a4ae9d, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/storage/9/d6/08/dogas/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
Category Products indexer process unknown error:
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php71/session/sess_8d4b0824fe8a35e6091a8fbec6a4ae9d, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/storage/9/d6/08/dogas/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
Product Categories indexer process unknown error:
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php71/session/sess_8d4b0824fe8a35e6091a8fbec6a4ae9d, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/storage/9/d6/08/dogas/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
Product Price indexer process unknown error:
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php71/session/sess_8d4b0824fe8a35e6091a8fbec6a4ae9d, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/storage/9/d6/08/dogas/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product indexer process unknown error:
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php71/session/sess_8d4b0824fe8a35e6091a8fbec6a4ae9d, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/storage/9/d6/08/dogas/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
Catalog Product Rule indexer process unknown error:
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php71/session/sess_8d4b0824fe8a35e6091a8fbec6a4ae9d, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/storage/9/d6/08/dogas/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php71/session/sess_8d4b0824fe8a35e6091a8fbec6a4ae9d, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/storage/9/d6/08/dogas/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
```

Vejo que tenho que dar permissão a algo mas não sei o que. Alguem poderia me ajudar por favor.

EDIT: Resolvido! Esse [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125264/magento-site-not-opening-after-cli-installation) me ajudou muito nisso.

- Eu só tive que adicionar o `session.save_path:`